# TypeError : List indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, api, google-api

Here is the code I am writing in Python 3. This is basically utilizing the Google Custom Search API.
I can't seem to get about this issue. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json
import sys
api_key = #key
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=my_key&q='
print("Search :")
search_query = sys.stdin.readline()
print("Loading...")
query = urllib.parse.quote(search_query)
rawData = urllib.request.urlopen(url+query).read()
jsonData = json.loads(rawData.decode('utf-8'))
results = jsonData['queries']['request']
for i in results:
    title = results['title']
    print(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of these is a list, not a dictionary:

```
jsonData
jsonData['queries']
jsonData['queries']['request']
```

Check the logs, and it will tell you which line of code is causing the key error.

Also, this does nothing but print the title several times (if it even exists):

```
for i in results:
    title = results['title']
    print(title)
```